# Output the result of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I simplify this stored procedure? It works but I think there is a better way than what I have.

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    TD.FoodName, SUM(TD.Number) AS OrderCount
INTO 
    #Stemp
FROM
    tblFactor
INNER JOIN 
    tblDetail TD ON tblFactor.Factor_ID = TD.Factor_ID
WHERE 
    FactorDate = @DayDate
GROUP BY 
    TD.FoodName
ORDER BY 
    ORDERCOUNT DESC

SELECT @foodName = FoodName, @OrderCount = OrderCount  
FROM #Stemp S
```

Here I use `#Stemp` table but I think is not necessary. I also use script like this but I get an error on `@OrderCount`:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DailyReport, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @FoodName = TD.FoodName, @OrderCount = SUM(TD.Number) AS OrderCount
FROM tblFactor
INNER JOIN tblDetail TD ON tblFactor.Factor_ID = TD.Factor_ID   
WHERE FactorDate = @DayDate
GROUP BY TD.FoodName
ORDER BY ORDERCOUNT DESC
```

`@FoodName` and `@OrderCount` are output parameters

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL statement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576). A [mre] includes sample data and the output you're hoping to obtain from that data, and the exact error message you're seeing if you're getting errors. Please [edit] your post to provide that additional information.

Comment: What error did it give on ordercount?

Comment: as you said there is no need to store them in a temp db unless you are using it later on in your SP

Comment: @KenWhite ,I add Error message

Comment: But you did not add sample data and the output you want to obtain from that data as I also asked. Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: @eshirvana yes but how I pass the foodName to '@foodName' and OrderCount to '@orderCount'  without #Stemp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign the variables directly in your select statement like so:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 @foodName= TD.FoodName, @OrderCount =SUM(TD.Number) 
    
    FROM tblFactor
    INNER JOIN tblDetail TD 
    ON tblFactor.Factor_ID = TD.Factor_ID
    WHERE FactorDate = @DayDate
    GROUP BY TD.FoodName
    ORDER BY SUM(TD.Number) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try leaving off the column alias since you won't have a column -- eg

```
SELECT TOP (1) @FoodName=TD.FoodName, @OrderCount =SUM(TD.Number)
```

and

```
ORDER BY SUM(TD.Number)
```

other than that you will need to tell us the error message in order to know what is going wrong.

---

or try this

```
SELECT TOP (1) @FoodName=Name, @OrderCount=oCount
FROM (
  SELECT TD.FoodName AS Name, SUM(TD.Number) AS oCount
  FROM tblFactor
  INNER JOIN tblDetail TD ON tblFactor.Factor_ID = TD.Factor_ID
  WHERE FactorDate = @DayDate
  GROUP BY TD.FoodName
)
ORDER BY oCount DESC
```

Comment: i dont know it is possible to remove alias because i order by OrderCount

Comment: in other word how can I refuse from #Stemp and  directly pass the food Name and orderCount to '@foodName' , and '@orderCount'